# What is the name of the japanese font used in Acchi Kocchi logo?

Tags: font-identification, japanese

[image: Acchi Kocchi Kindergarten]
I mean the font of the biggest purple letters.

It says あっちこっち幼稚園

I've searched in google and Whatthefont with no results.

Point to look at:

- The hiraganas あ and こ have arrows added.

Comment: I don't think whatthefont supports Japanese characters. Try http://en.likefont.com/ instead. It can find some fonts which are close, but not an exact match. Perhaps it's not a font - it could be a custom design, or the characters could have been modified. Not everything is a font!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo uses a font [タカライン](http://designpocket.jp/dl_font_category/detail.aspx?bid=3241) created by [Shin'ichi Takahara](http://www.takadpro.com/), with roundedness and other necessary modification added. The kana and kanji also seem taken from different weights of the family, respectively.

[image]

(example using タカライン H)

Answer (score 0):

I  checked the major japanese font makers (C&G, DynaCom, Fontworks, Iwata, Morisawa, Motoya, Screen, Typebank, VDL) catalogs, but couldn't find a match. Most probably it is a "design" (デサイン書体, not gothic or ゴシック) font, with some edge rounding. The arrows were most probably added later, because one of the main visual elements of the anime were arrows.